# How do I attach the console to Xcode IDE

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, xcode3.2

I'd like to know if there is a way to show the Application Console on start in Xcode 3.

Every time I run the program, I have to click on the Show Console button.

I'm running Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Xcode 3.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Preferences` => `Debugging` => `On Start:` => `Show Console`